# Generate pattern using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a single column with numbers 1-100. Want to generate an output where each number `N` is repeated `N` times (so `5` should appear 5 times):

```
1
2
2
3
3
3
4
4
4
4
and so on
```

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: I recommend using some sort of scripting language to manage this

Comment: @jarlh any version will be fine!

Comment: @jarlh is probably asking because, depending from the mysql version some features can or cannot be available

Comment: @jarlh MySQL 5.7. Thanks!

Comment: @Analyst14 A recursive query with a self-join should return the expected result.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 is probably too old for recursive cte's. (Version 8 needed?)

Comment: @jarlh yes, I checked that. In `mysql` cte are implemented from 8.0 and on.

Comment: *"MySQL 5.7 is probably too old for recursive cte's"* @jarlh MySQL 5.7 should already had support for it.. in my opinion ideally as soon as MySQL 5.1 (released in 2008) should already had CTE, CTE are a SQL 2003 standard.. I saw some 3th party storage engines/MySQL source code rewrites (not talking about MariaDB here) with including windows functions and `CHECK` constraint for MySQL 5.5/5.7 i believe in the past.

Comment: Topicstarter This should be done in a programming lauguage (double loops) not in SQL or you need to write a stored procedure which does the double looping, Recursive cte's are not really suited for this..

Answer (score 0):

For `mysql` versions prior to `8.0`,

```
create table _set(n int);

insert into _set(n) values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6); -- this goes on

select s2.* from _set as s
  join _set as s2 on s.n <= s2.n;
```

Temporary tables can't be opened twice [documented issue](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10327).

For `mysql` versions `8.0`, try this,

```
with _set as (select 1 as n 
            union all
            select n+1 as n from _set
            where n < 100
            )
select s2.* from _set s
    join _set s2 on s.n <= s2.n
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySql 5.x

Create a tally table with positive numbers, including 0.

Then self-join that number table.

```
select n1.n as num
from nums as n1
join nums as n2 on n2.n < n1.n
where n1.n between 1 and 100
order by n1.n;
```

An example of creating such a number table:

```
CREATE TABLE digits (n int primary key not null);

insert into digits (n) values 
(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9);

CREATE TABLE nums (n int primary key not null);

-- fill with numbers 0 to 999
INSERT INTO nums (n)
SELECT (d3.n*100 + d2.n*10 + d1.n) as num
FROM digits d1
CROSS JOIN digits d2
CROSS JOIN digits d3;
```

In  MySql 8 a recursive CTE can be used instead

```
WITH RECURSIVE NUMS AS 
(
  SELECT 0 as n

  UNION ALL

  SELECT n+1
  FROM NUMS
  WHERE n < 100
)
SELECT n1.n
FROM NUMS n1
JOIN NUMS n2 ON n2.n < n1.n
ORDER BY n1.n;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table with numbers, then use it in a self join:

```
select n.n
from numbers n join
     numbers n2
     on n2.n <= n.n
order by n.n;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=67d1edb88f717d89356587dfc81d0b37) is a db<>fiddle example.